# Can't pass properties to angular directive constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I'm trying to give a directive a reference to its element, but I can't pass it in the constructor. What's really weird is that I have a different directive in the same project that *does* get a reference to its element through the constructor.

Here's a bunch of different things I've tried:

first, the one that works on a different directive elsewhere in the project:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'dialog[openable]'
})
export class OpenableDirective {
  constructor (private readonly element: ElementRef) { }
}
```

okay, maybe it can't be readonly:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'dialog[openable]'
})
export class OpenableDirective {
  constructor (private element: ElementRef) { }
}
```

let's try `public`:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'dialog[openable]'
})
export class OpenableDirective {
  constructor (public element: ElementRef) { }
}
```

okay, how about doing it a dumb way:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'dialog[openable]'
})
export class OpenableDirective {
  private element: ElementRef;
  constructor (e: ElementRef) {
    this.element = e;
  }
}
```

These all fail to compile with the same error message:

```
ERROR in /path/to/src/app/directives/openable.directive.spec.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /path/to/src/app/directives/openable.directive.spec.ts(5,23)
      TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.1 autonomous:build: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --no-progress --no-colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

of course, you'll notice that line 5 not only doesn't have 23 columns, but it's also not where the error comes from. I know this because this code:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'dialog[openable]'
})
export class OpenableDirective {
  constructor () { }
}
```

compiles fine.

Why is this broken? Why does it work elsewhere?

Comment: The errors refers to your `/openable.directive.spec.ts` <-- spec/test file. What's in your test.

Comment: try using `ElementRef<HTMLElement>` instead.

Comment: 0.o how did I miss that? There's an auto-generated spec file and obviously the constructor call signature didn't update when I changed it in the source file.